# Load video and Photos in PhotoLibrary to a collection view

Tags: video, swift3, photos, collectionview

I'm trying to load all videos and photos from photo library to a `collectionView`. I got code from [stackOver flow link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892028/how-to-load-the-photo-library-into-uicollectionview-swifthttp://). But it's crashing with in the `viewwillAppear` function saying found nil while unwrapping optional value. I tried it in both device and simulator. I'm adding the same code below.

```
import UIKit
import Photos


class TestViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraRollCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!
var assetThumbnailSize: CGSize!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Get size of the collectionView cell for thumbnail image
    if let layout = self.cameraRollCollectionView!.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        let cellSize = layout.itemSize

        self.assetThumbnailSize = CGSize(width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
    }

    //fetch the photos from collection
    self.photosAsset = (PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options: nil) as AnyObject!) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!


    self.cameraRollCollectionView!.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    var count: Int = 0

    if(self.photosAsset != nil){
        count = self.photosAsset.count
    }

    return count;
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cameraCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UserImagesCollectionViewCell

    //Modify the cell
    let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if result != nil {
            cell.userImage.image = result
        }
    })

    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods
func collectionView(collectinView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

// UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

> The crash point is :

```
 //fetch the photos from collection
self.photosAsset = (PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options: nil) as AnyObject!) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!
```

Please please help me to with this.

Thank you

Comment: Xcode should have told you which line "found nil while unwrapping optional value", providing this information can help us find your problems

Comment: within the viewWillAppear func...

 //fetch the photos from collection
    self.photosAsset = (PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options: nil) as AnyObject!) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!

at this point

Comment: any one please help me @aahung

Comment: @JaisanMathew How are you getting all the Videos?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have the "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" in your "Info.plist". (See image below) This step will enable your App to ask for Photo Library permission.

[image: Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description]

2. Make sure you have at least one "Album" in your photo library. Or you might consider change the line `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, ...` to `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .any, ...`. "SmartAlbum" can find "CameraRoll".

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to .moment instead of .album. That is work for me in Swift 4.

```
let collection : PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .moment, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
```